# I need to know how to tell if no radio button is set

Tags: php

I need to know how to tell if no radio button is set.  I have a jquery example that works in my javascript validation routines it looks like this:

```
function validate_veteran($form) {
    if ($('input[name=veteran]:checked').length <1) {
        return "please make a selection for veteran.<br>";
    }
    return "";
    }
```

If I can find a way to do this in PHP I'll be set.

Comment: `isset($_POST['veteran'])` assuming its a post request

Comment: PHP doesn't have radio buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!isset($_POST['veteran']))
{
    echo "please make a selection for veteran.<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the `value` attributes that you gave the checkbox in your HTML markup, you can test for the existence of a value there.

Assuming the form was sent with the POST method -

```
if (isset($_POST['veteran'])){
   // there is a value
}
```

If you set a specific value then you can test for it.

```
<input type="radio" value="yes" name="veteran" />
```

```
if ($_POST['veteran'] == 'yes'){
  // value is set to yes
}
```

How you decide to act after you have detected a problem is up to you and how you have structured your site. You might want to redirect the user to an error page detailing the problems or you might be returning a JSON object with status and error parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify if a value was sent to your php script

```
if (empty($_REQUEST['veteran'])) {
    // user did not selected a radio option
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery solution**
If you want to validate the form before sending it to the browser.
I suppose that your validating button is :

```
<input type="submit" id="send" value="Send" />
```

you will have a validation process summarized like this :

```
jQuery('#send') .click(function(){
if($('#radio_button').is(':checked')){
     alert("Please make a selection for veteran.<br>");
      return false;/*important! prevents the form from being sent  */
     }
});
```

**PHP solution**
If javascript is not enabled or is not supported
This will work for GET or POST method, but here is an example with POST.

```
if (!isset($_POST['veteran']) || empty($_POST['veteran']))
{
    echo "please make a selection for veteran.<br>";
}
```

NOTE : you may want to check if the radion button was not assigned an empty value by some browser plugins or else.